# Eclipse Juno update from SR1 breaks everything

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

I have been running Eclipse Juno SR1 for quite a while. My Eclipse IDE is in a Ubuntu 12.10 VM running as guest in VirtualBox under Windows 7. It has been stable but extremely slow.  The performance issue was preventing me from working, so I tried to update as described at http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_UI/Juno_Performance_Investigation

Now, Eclipse is dead - totally unusable. In the project file navigator, I see messages such as "Could not create the view: org.eclipse.ant.ui.views.AntView", "Could not create the view: org.eclipse.php.ui.explorer", "Could not create the view: org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer" and "Could not create the view: org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.PackageExplo".  The error log contains many entries referencing images, like "!MESSAGE Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/com.aptana.terminal/icons/terminal.png"." and "!MESSAGE Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/com.aptana.scripting.ui/icons/snippet.png".".

I went in to check the eclipse.ini file, and found only a file named "eclipse.ini.ignored" which contains:

```
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product 
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-configuration
../../home/myuser/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.0_1473617060/configuration
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

I made a backup of my entire VM about a week ago, if that is the best method of recovery.

Any assistance you can offer would be appreciated. I can post log and configuration files if they'd be helpful.